# How to PARSE a data string in query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains a customer account number and **ONE** field which contains multiple customer notes.  I need to extract the customer notes into separate line item results in my query.  I have included a sample of my data and the expected output of my query below.

```
**TABLE**

***Customer #*** ***Customer Notes***
=====================================    
25214 | 05/01/2014 - New Customer setup. - DAB |05/24/2014 - Waive Deposit. - DAB
12254 | 03/15/2013 - VIP customer. - FLH |03/23/2014 - See John if there is a 
        problem with customer's account. - FLH
```

The Customer Notes data field is a TEXT data type.  As you can see, for each account number there are two customer notes for each customer.  I need to PARSE the data in the Customer Notes data field and have the following results:

```
25214 | 05/01/2014 - New Customer setup. - DAB    
25214 | 05/24/2014 - Waive Deposit. - DAB    
12254 | 03/15/2014 - VIP Customer. - FLH    
12254 | 03/23/2014 - See John if there is a problem with customer's account. - FLH
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Use [this Split function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/).

Comment: SQL Server is not designed to do things like this.  You are working with a terrible database design here and if it's possible, you should refactor the design.  If you don't you will continue to face challenges like this until you eventually go crazy.  If you can't refactor, return this data to a programming language that is more suited for parsing.

Comment: That particular split function is known as a nibbler. It will work but is probably the slowest of all the different types of t-sql splitters. It is using a while and is also the worst kind of table valued function, the multi statement version. You would do well to find just about any other splitter anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an option to redesign the table as suggested by @Abe Miessler, you can try the following.

```
declare @table as table (AccountNumber int, Notes varchar(4000))

insert into @table values(25214,'|05/01/2014 - New Customer setup. - DAB |05/24/2014 - Waive Deposit. - DAB');
insert into @table values(12254,'|03/15/2013 - VIP customer. - FLH |03/23/2014 - See John if there is a problem with customer''s account. - FLH');

SELECT AccountNumber, Notes.n.value('.','varchar(4000)') as Notes
  FROM (SELECT 
            AccountNumber, 
            CAST(replace(replace(replace((SELECT Notes FOR XML PATH('')),
                     '|','</n><n>|'),
                     '<Notes></n>','<Notes>'),
                     '</Notes>','</n></Notes>') AS XML) AS XNotes
         FROM @table) as t
CROSS APPLY XNotes.nodes('/Notes/n') as Notes(n)
```

The query transforms the `Notes` column into XML and then uses T-SQL XML functions to pull the data into rows.

---

**OUTPUT**

```
AccountNumber Notes
------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
25214         |05/01/2014 - New Customer setup. - DAB 
25214         |05/24/2014 - Waive Deposit. - DAB
12254         |03/15/2013 - VIP customer. - FLH 
12254         |03/23/2014 - See John if there is a problem with customer's account. - FLH
```

---

**Reference:**

- [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)
- [value() Method (xml Data
  Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

---

**EDIT:**
Properly escape special characters in Notes for XML. Added sample output.

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique delimiter.  I can't tell if the pipe is part of your actual data or not...so using date pattern for this example:

```
declare @table table (CustID int,Note varchar(max))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (25214, '05/01/2014 - New Customer setup. - DAB |05/24/2014 - Waive Deposit. - DAB')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (12254, '03/15/2013 - VIP customer. - FLH |03/23/2014 - See John if there is a problem with customer''s account. - FLH')

SELECT CustID,
       left(Note,patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', right(Note,len(Note)-1))) as Note
FROM @table

UNION

SELECT CustID,
       right(Note,len(Note) - patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', right(Note,len(Note)-1))) as Note
FROM @table
```